# ColorConversionStrategy CMYK adds a white background

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, postscript, cmyk

i have a strange problem with the behaviour of the option ColorConversionStrategy CMYK in GS 9.16.

Attached are two pdfs one that uses /ColorConversionStrategy /CMYK and one that uses LeaveColorUnchanged.

Broken file that uses CMYK Conversion :https://traffiq.synology.me/owncloud/index.php/s/193xmAAl2RFYaWn

Okay file that uses the Default value ( but uses RGB which is not what i want )
https://traffiq.synology.me/owncloud/index.php/s/roisvD2sp0W3Wsv

The funny thing is that /ColorConversionStrategy /CMYK seems to add a white background so it blocks out the right part of the page.

I wasted an entire day on that issue and can't for the life of me figure out what the problem seems to be.

Can someone have a look please and give me hint ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you open a bug report. Don't forget to supply the original PDF file and the *exact* (and preferably minimal) command line needed to reproduce the problem. By the way, You say that leaving the color conversion strategy at default uses CMYK which you don;t want, and then you go and set /CMYK, bit confused there.... FWIW the most likely problem is that the PDF users transparency, and we don't currently alter the blending space of transparency groups, which can lead to surprising effects.

Comment: Hi,thanks for the answer i will open a bug report. The "okay file" produces RGB not CMYK, so that was a typo.

Comment: */CMYK seems to add a white background* - Looking at your files it indeed does! it has a `1 g 0 0 11900 8420 re f` at the start of the second content stream of your page while the version without does not.

Comment: I opened a bug report but it died :/